# ProgressDialog is not working in Ginger Bread but works in ICS ad JB

Tags: android, progressdialog

i have a feature to use webviews in my application i have used "ProgressDialog" api its not working in my phone( Ginger Bread ), but i tried the same thing in Emulator(ICS & JB) it was working fine.

```
public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
  if (progressDialog == null) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...Please wait");
    progressDialog.show();
  }
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
  System.out.println("Loading...onPageFinished");

  if (progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some java code?

Comment: What code are you using to display your ProgressDialog ?

Comment: public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
         if (progressDialog == null) {
             progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...Please wait");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         System.out.println("Loading...onPageFinished");
            if (progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
         }

Comment: @krishna5115 It is better that you edit your question and put code there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`onPageStarted`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) instead of `onLoadResource` :

```
public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
  if (progressDialog == null) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...Please wait");
    progressDialog.show();
  }
}
```

And be sure to check if your `progressDialog` isn't null and show your `Dialog` (in case you already have loaded an URL)

Comment: Can you dig with breakpoint in this function ? Does it go through her when you load your URL ? Can you post (in edit) your calling line ?

Comment: Yeah actually i have added some print statements into that function and able to see that print statements on my console also.

Comment: How you load your URL ? What is the execution order you can determine with your log ?

Answer (score 0):

solved by myself with self digging in some forms/blogs.  In my code am not making progressDialog to null after dismissing.  find my updated code if any one wants progress thing or any issue.`progressDialog = null;`